# How to sort numbers in two lists using FOR loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, integer

```
num1 = [1, 3, 5]
num2 = [2, 4, 6]
```

I have these two lists and need to use a FOR-Loop to organize them so that the print statement prints out the values like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I have tried this: for value in num1 and num2:

```
if num1[0] > num2[0]:
    print num1
else: 
    print num2
```

Nothing I have tried has worked :(
This is my first coding class pls help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve]. Oh, and don't forget to tell us what language you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming python, use:

```
for x, y in zip(num1, num2):
    print x
    print y
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Annoying how simple the answer ended up being given the amount of time I've spent figuring this out!

Comment: @SebastianMachado Happy to help :-) please accept it too.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude He should also look at that link

Comment: Much appreciated! Accepted and noted for future questions

Answer (score 0):

```
let num1=[1, 3, 5],num2 = [2, 4, 6]
let arr=num1.concat(num2).sort((a,b)=>a-b)
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    console.log(arr[i])
}
```

Comment: The question has a `python` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[1,3,5]
y=[2,4,6]
z=x+y
z.sort()
for i in z:
    print (i)
```

output:
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6